# Type Sequence does not conform to protocol _Sequence (Swift Beta 4)

Tags: swift

The following code that previously worked fine in Swift Beta 2 no longer compiles in Beta 4. Can anyone explain why, please?

```
for dx in [-1, 0, 1] { // Fine
    for dy in (dx == 0) ? [-1, 1] : [0, (xIndex % 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1] { // Now fails
       // ...
    }
}
```

The error given is "Type 'Sequence' does not conform to protocol '_Sequence'". I know how to fix it (just set the inner range explicitly instead of using the ? operator), but why is this now an illegal expression?

The full function is:

```
func tilesAdjacentTo(#xIndex: Int, yIndex: Int) -> [HexTile] {
    var adjacent = [HexTile]()
    // We want to do this, where dy is -1 for even columns and +1 for odd
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex + 0][yIndex + 1]
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex + 0][yIndex - 1]
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex + 1][yIndex + 0]
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex + 1][yIndex + dy]
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex - 1][yIndex + 0]
    // adjacent += self.pieces[xIndex - 1][yIndex + dy]
    for dx in [-1, 0, 1] {
        for dy in (dx == 0) ? [-1, 1] : [0, (xIndex % 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1] {
            let x = xIndex + dx
            let y = yIndex + dy
            if (x > 0) &&
                (x <= self.maxX) &&
                (y > 0) &&
                (y <= self.maxY)
            {
                adjacent += self.pieces[x][y]
            }
        }
    }
    //println("Adjacent \(adjacent.count)")
    return adjacent
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the declaration of the variable xIndex in your code sample?

Comment: No, @AnthonyKong - I've updated the question with more context. Thanks.

Comment: The code does not really compile due to the missing HexTile class declaration. Anyway, your code was working in beta 3 too. But considering swift is still very young, we should not be surprised of any syntax change. Besdies, the code will be cleaner if you break it down into multiple lines

Comment: Well, I'm sorry - SO asks for minimal code examples. Please go back to the initial fragment and let xIndex be an Int. If you want I can send you the whole source with the definition of HexTile too, but it really doesn't elaborate the question. The question is why doesn't the second line of the original post compile now?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, swift is a very young language and is still evolving. The creators of the language may consider this syntax as illegal now. But if you do not agree, you really should report it as a bug to Apple. Afterall XCode 6 beta 4 seems to be very buggy (that's why I am holding on to beta 3)